# How to make pop-up alert which is like MSN when friends get online

Tags: popup

I would like to know how to make pop-up alert which is like MSN when friends get online.
The pop-up alert will fade in the right-bottom of the window and will fade out after 3 seconds.

I am using C# (VS2005). 
Please kindly advice me if any tech tools i should apply or any method to do. 
many thanks!!:)

Answer (score 0):

In GWT (java-based web framework), you can use [gwt-comet](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/).

I think you can integrate it with any server (IIS and .net) scince, GWT is a user-interface framework